# React App production build blank has nothing but a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am quite new to react (and still learning), so I apologize if the problem is too basic.

I have created a shoe store App (inspired by this tutorial on [React Router v6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NpGzBEySvI))

The problem I am facing is that the App works perfectly on development build.

[image: GIF of working dev build]

But when I create a production build (`yarn build`) and serve it using `npx serve -s build`, I get an empty page

[image: Production build screenshot]

The console gives an error that `shoeData` (a javascript object on a separate `shoeData.js` file with named export.) is not defined. There was no such error on development build. In fact, just before the errors on the console in the production build, an array has been logged twice using the following code

```js
console.log(Object.keys(shoeData).filter((productId) => shoeData[productId].featured));
```

The above code uses the `shoeData` object, therefore the object is available to the component at least initially.

I have also modified the `package.json` to add `"homepage": "."` since people have solved similar issues using this fix, but it doesn't work in this case.

The complete project is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/uzair-suria/uas-shoe-store)

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated

Comment: You would need to serve your build folder i.e. all the static files, minified js etc.. on a server like express js or using react on rails

Comment: Actually, I set the project as CICD and it automatically builds the app and deploys the production build to uas-shoe-store.surge.sh upon each commit to master. I implemented the CICD when I created the app initially using `create-react-app` and the initial template was deployed without any problem. But the problem I wrote about is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/uzair-suria/uas-shoe-store/blob/master/src/components/CarouselCard.js#L40) looks weird，you should pass string to `src` rather than require a file.

I just clone the repo and make sure the problem is cause by `require()`.

Steps to fix:

1. Move `images/` into `public/` folder
2. Replace **all** `require('...').default` with image url, such as `/images/${shoeData[productId].gender}/${productId}/01.jpg`.
3. Remove `homepage` field from package.json

Comment: Adding assets to public folder isn't generally recommended and I want to follow this recommendation if at all possible. What I am trying to achieve is not so uncommon, there should be a way to do. Do you have any work around in mind?

Comment: Actually, adding assets to public folder is recommended by [create-react-app doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder#when-to-use-the-public-folder).

Comment: And most common way is adding assets to public folder, then upload them to CDN in prod build.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'll try your suggested way and then mark the question as answered

Comment: Turns out in JS code, `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` has to be used. As far as I can tell, everything is working fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What I can see on url is that, ReferenceError: shoeData is not defined is being shown. Please look after it.

I'm also looking what's the reason just cloning the repo